# scaling twice as large iPad Pro

Tags: css

I am currently trying to create a simple website with a few images and text developed in a grid layout css. I used the iPad Pro 2732x2048px as a reference for the layout. When I host the website on my webspace and display it in the browser it is twice as big, zoom is at 100%. On my PC it is scaled normally. Do I need a special meta tag for the ipad Pro?

I used the following meta tag

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.